# Can't read lines from a text file

Tags: java, android

I have a method like this:

```
    public int getIncrement() {

    String extractFolder = "/mnt/sdcard/MyFolder";
    boolean newFolder = new File(extractFolder).mkdir();
    int counter = 0; 

    try {
        File root = new File(extractFolder); 
        if (root.canWrite()){
            File gpxfile = new File(root, "gpxfile.txt");
            FileWriter gpxwriter = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(gpxwriter);

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(gpxfile.getAbsolutePath()), "UTF-8");
            Log.i("PATH: ", extractFolder + "/gpxfile.txt");

           while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
               String inc = scanner.nextLine(); 
               counter = Integer.parseInt(inc);
               Log.i("INSIDE WHILE: ", Integer.toString(counter)); 
           }
            counter++;
            out.write(Integer.toString(counter));
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GEN_PCN: ", "Could not write file " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return counter;  
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is returning the content of this file, and increment the `integer` by 1. But it seems that I can't get in the `while` loop, because `LogCat` doesn't print out anything. Yes, am sure that the path is correct.

Comment: Got the proper permission to write to the external storage? Without that, `canWrite()` will return false and the majority of your code will be skipped.

Comment: Yeah, i defined in my manifest file that I can write to external storage

Comment: What do you expect to be in the file?  It looks like you are trying to read from a file in a newly created directory (presumably empty).  If the file is empty, there should be nothing to read and thus scanner.hasNextLine() should return false.

Comment: Does the file gpxfile.txt exist already? Or are you trying to create it here?

Comment: I except a number, the file only contains a number, which will be incremented after I've read the content of the file.

Comment: What does gpxfile.exists() return?  If it is false, then the file doesn't exist and you cannot read anything from it.

Comment: before I try to do a while(scanner.hasNextLine()) the file does exist.

Comment: As another poster pointed out, it could be created by the FileWriter as an empty file.  If you really want to write the incremented digit to the file after you read it, you should open the file for writing after you've closed it for reading.  That might make things clearer.

Comment: **Just try BACKSLAH / at end of your extractFolder**

Comment: **Have You Solved This Problem???**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the constructor of  `FileWriter gpxwriter` has already blanked out the file by the time the `Scanner` is created, so the file is empty and `hasNextLine` returns `false`. Why do you open a file for writing when you want to read it?

Comment: First of all, I want to read the content of the file. After I have got the content of the file. Return this value. After that, I want to overwrite the content, or increment the content by one.

Comment: just to test my theory, open the file with the "append" parameter, i.e. `FileWriter gpxwriter = new FileWriter(gpxfile,true);` to keep it intact.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell the file doesn't exist. Try adding gpxfile.createNewFile()

To get a little more in depth, creating a File instance, does not create a file on the file system.

So, this line -> File gpxfile = new File(path, filename);

is not sufficient to create the file on the sd card. You must follow it with

gpxfile.createNewFile() which quoting the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29) says:

> Atomically creates a new, empty file named by this abstract pathname if and only if a file with this name does not yet exist. The check for the existence of the file and the creation of the file if it does not exist are a single operation that is atomic with respect to all other filesystem activities that might affect the file.

Answer (score 0):

**OK I MARK YOUR FILE NAME**

Just add a **BACKSLASH** in extractFolder **at END**

```
                                            v
                                            v
                                            v
String extractFolder = "/mnt/sdcard/MyFolder/";
                                            ^ // <---   HERE
                                            ^
                                            ^
```

Because **File gpxfile = new File(root, "gpxfile.txt");** doesn't have **BackSlash /** as **Log** have

---

Just try Once Following:

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
      String inc = scanner.nextLine(); 
      //       //   counter = Integer.parseInt(inc);
      Log.i("INSIDE WHILE: ", inc);
      System.out.println("Next Line ::"+inc);  //  Also check this
}
```

Comment: this doesnt make sense, if you read my post, it says that I can't access the while loop.

Comment: Then the problem is that you are not getting data in scanner.

Comment: His filename is specified in the File he is trying to read and write to (gpxfile).

Comment: **Ok I marked it. Now SEE MY MOST EDITED ANSWER IN ABOVE; it is about BACKSLAH /**